# htaccess throws 500 Internal error

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory structure with a subdirectory `XYZ` and `index.php` file. XYZ contains has few more child directories for css, images, js etc. I am trying to accomplish following:

1. gallery, img, css, js path should map to XYZ's subdirectories of the
   same name
2. every single url such as `http://example.com/my-page` should map to `http://example.com/xyz?route=my-page`

Below is my .htaccess file, please help.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?:gallery|img|css|js).*)$ xyz/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xyz/?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Your error log should give you details of what is wrong with your configuration

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?:gallery|img|css|js)/.*$ xyz/$0 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ xyz/?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```